# avoid converting iterator to list whenever possible

Tags: python, iterator

Suppose I have a function taking one parameter, an *iterable*, as input, and I want to iterate more than once on the iterable.

If I write it like this:

```
def a_function(an_iterable):
    for x in an_iterable:
       print(x)
    for x in an_iterable:
       print(x)
```

the second loop *may* be executed or not.

- it is executed if the iterable is a `list`, `set`, `dict`, which are not iterator/generator functions, or `range` which rearms itself
- not for a custom generator function or a file object (obtained with `f=open("file")`). (the reuse of a file iterator is the subject of many questions here at SO)

Of course, I could do this to avoid creating an unnecessary `list` if not needed:

```
def a_function(an_iterable):
    if any(lambda x : type(an_iterable==x) for x in (range,list,set,dict))):
        # use as-is
        pass
    else:
         an_iterable = list(an_iterable)

    for x in an_iterable:
       print(x)
    for x in an_iterable:
       print(x)
```

that would work for a lot of common cases, but not the general case.

**Is there a clean way to detect if I can iterate many times on my iterable object?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`collections.abc.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence) class to see if the iterable is actually a sequence:

```
>>> from collections.abc import Sequence
>>> isinstance([1,2,3], Sequence)
True
>>> isinstance((1,2,3), Sequence)
True
>>> isinstance(range(10), Sequence)
True
>>> isinstance(iter((1,2,3)), Sequence)
False
```

This wont work for sets:

```
>>> isinstance({1,2,3}, Sequence)
False
```

If you want to include sets and mappings use the [`collections.abs.Set`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Set) and [`collections.abc.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping):

```
>>> isinstance({1,2,3}, (Sequence, Set, Mapping))
True
```

You may want to create an helper function that converts an iterable to a sequence if needed:

```
def sequencify(iterable):
    if isinstance(iterable, (Sequence, Set, Mapping)):
        return iterable
    return list(iterable)
```

And now you can just do:

```
def a_function(iterable):
    iterable = sequencify(iterable)

    for x in iterable:
        print(x)
    for x in iterable:
        print(x)
```

---

A simpler alternative is to check that `iterable` argument does *not* have a `__next__` method:

```
>>> hasattr([1,2,3], '__next__')
False
>>> hasattr(iter([1,2,3]), '__next__')
True
```

This works because well-implemented containers are only iterables and not iterator themselves, so they only have an `__iter__` method that returns an iterator which has the `__next__` method that advances the iteration.

This would lead to:

```
def sequencify(iterable):
    if not hasattr(iterable, '__next__'):
        return iterable
    return list(iterable)
```

---

The final alternative is the simplest: document the argument as a *sequence* and **not** an *iterable* and let the user be responsible for providing the correct type.

Comment: another precision: what if I create a function using `yield` ? It has no `__next__` but isn't "rearmable". Isn't it a special case? could we just check it with `hasattr(it,"__code__")`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre check if it is `callable`? The issue is that you do not know the parameters to call it...

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether the object has a [`__next__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) method (Python 3), or a [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next) method (Python 2). If it does then you might assume that it implements the iterator protocol and its values will therefore not be reusable.

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> it = iter(l)
>>> hasattr(l, '__next__')
False
>>> hasattr(it, '__next__')
True
```

If there is a `__next__` attribute you should then check that it is callable:

```
>>> hasattr(l, '__next__') and callable(l.__next__)
False
>>> hasattr(it, '__next__') and callable(it.__next__)
True
```